# Sort aligned columns

Tags: scripting, sort

I have a program which output looks like this

```
 #         Status   VAL1   VAL2   Description
 1      some text    2.5    4.4   Some long other text
 5    some text 2   14.5    2.0   Some long other text 2
12    some text 3  222.6   24.4   Some long other text 3
19    some text 4    3.4    1.5   Some long other text 4
21    some text 5   55.4   10.6   Some long other text 5
32    some text 6    2.9    9.4   Some long other text 6
```

I'd like to sort along the VAL2 column. I tried with `sort -k 4` but when there's spaces in the Status column `sort` get confused.

Is there a way to work around this? Maybe to pass a character number instead of a field number?

Comment: Yes, that can be done, look up the `-k` option to `sort(1)`. Just make sure the input file doesn't contain tabs, as they will throw off your count (`expand(1)`)

Comment: @vonbrand it won't work that way, cause sort will take any space sequence as field delimiter and you cannot predict which one will be on forth column. furthermore it won't be VAL2.

Comment: @rush, just tell sort that the field delimiter is something impossible, and count characters in the first "field" (the full line).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort based on column offset:

```
sort -k1.27g
```

Note that the `g` flag above (for general numeric sorting) is not standard so may not be supported by your  sort implementation.

With that particular data sample, you can get away with:

```
LC_ALL=C sort -k1.27
```

That is do an alphanumeric sort and use the C locale to make sure the leading spaces are not ignored in the sorting. So for instance `[ ]4.4` sorts before `24.4` even though `4` sorts after `2`.